# How to run script after generate template using hygen?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using [hygen](https://github.com/jondot/hygen) to create templates for my project.

How to run a script (nodejs) after `hygen` command complete in **hygen way**?

```
hygen my-package new awsome-package
```

For example after this command I want to add line to `tsconfig.json` in the current project.

Comment: Sounds like you're asking a question about running a command in bash rather than about node.js. Did you try something like `hygen my-package new awsome-package && echo "the line you want to add" >> tsconfig.json`

Comment: I want it in one command by hygen way. of course I can do just nodejs file and run the file, but I want to do it with as hygen command

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In hygen you have [Shell option](https://github.com/jondot/hygen/blob/master/content/docs/templates.md#shell)

This is mean that you can run a shell command (script), you just create a file and insert the following content for example:

```
 ---
 sh: "mkdir -p <%= cwd %>/given/app/shell && cat > <%= cwd %>/given/app/shell/hello.piped"
 ---
 hello, this was piped!
```

When you run your command then hello.piped will have `hello, this was piped!` text just by cmd command.

In this example, you can add a package to package.json and then run yarn install.

```
---
inject: true
to: package.json
after: dependencies
skip_if: lodash
sh: cd <%= cwd %> && yarn install
---
"lodash":"*",
```

Comment: What if you want to do it at the very end of the code generation?

Answer (score 1):

I found that hygen runs the template files in alphabetical order.

So to make your shell command run last, you can prepend a number to each of the template filenames to control their order.